# Can we remove a security group from an running EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running EC2 instance with few security groups added. What I want to do is to remove one of the security group and add a new one.

I think there will be no problem in adding a new security group. But is it possible to remove a security group without terminating existing ec2 instance and creating a new one from the ami ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, it is possible both to add and remove security group. In AWS web console go to EC2 Instances page, right click on instance you want to change -> Networking -> Change Security Group
You can easily check that it is done without terminating or even stopping the instance.

Answer (score 3):

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/working-with-security-groups.html#changing-security-group) this is how you can remove a security group from a insance:

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Instances.
3. Select your instance, and then choose Actions, Security, Change
   security groups.
4. For Associated security groups, select a security group from the
   list and choose Add security group.
5. To remove an already associated security group, choose Remove for
   that security group.
6. Choose Save.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, you can also change the inbound/outbound rules of the current security group instead of removing it and adding a new one. Changes to inbound/outbound rules also take effect immediately with no need to stop EC2.